# where do I change the src type? for example child-src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, src

Im gettting a `Content Security Policy: Directive ‘frame-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘child-src’ instead.` Now iv read alot about this and it makes sense.. however where do i find the file to change this to `child-src`?

It seems when i use just src in my html i get this warning. I have two cases where it does this.

1

```html
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>" data-amount="<%= @charge_stripe %>" data-name="ScribeOwl" data-description="Reviser help for <%= session[:writing_type] %>" data-label="Ask for Reviser Help"
  data-alipay="true" data-currency="usd" data-image="/assets/scribe-owl.jpg" data-locale="auto">
</script>
```

2

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

I obviously need to change the src type!! where is the location of this default so I can change it?? all in all where do i find `frame-src` so i can change it to `child-src`?

Comment: The warning is not from the script tag element - rather the stripe javascript probally creates an iframe. I'm guessing you can ignore the warning until Stripe fixes it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/child-src